# Changing a tex4ht css class

Tags: tex4ht

I am using htxelatex to convert a tex file + config file of my own. I want to change the generated css objects but I can't seem to be able to.

### What I am doing

In my config file I use the following

```
\Css { .cmcsc-10x-x-248{font-size:90\%;} }
```

But my generated css keeps the original size

```
.cmcsc-10x-x-248{font-size:206%;}
```

Is there a way to edit that class from my config file without using another method (scripting), I want to edit several of them.

Here are some working demos. I just want to make the font smaller.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\newenvironment{LOGOAMIGE}{}{~\\[1cm] 
\vspace{2in}}
\newenvironment{navbartext}{}{}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.2mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
% only works if a paragraph has started.
\begin{LOGOAMIGE}
  THELOGO
\end{LOGOAMIGE}
\begin{navbartext}
    \huge \textsc{Digitarc PX3\texttrademark System}\\[0.1cm]
\end{navbartext}
\begin{navbartext}
    \huge \textsc{Electrode Arc Regulator}
\end{navbartext}


\vfill
\begin{navbartext}
% Bottom of the page
    User Manual\\[0.5cm]
    \Large EAF 1.3
\end{navbartext}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

and the config file

```
\edef\hash{\string#}
\Preamble{xhtml}
  \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />\Hnewline}}
  \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />\Hnewline}}

\begin{document}
  \ConfigureEnv{titlepage}
    {\HCode {<header class="navbar navbar-bright navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">}} 
    {\HCode {</div></header>}} {} {}
  \ConfigureEnv{LOGOAMIGE}
    {\HCode {
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="\#main-nav">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a href="\#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top">
    }}
    {\HCode {
      </a>
      </div>
      <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    }}
  \Css { .cmcsc-10x-x-248{font-size:90\%;} } 

\makeatletter
\let\ifes@LaTeXe\iftrue
\makeatother
\Configure{BODY}{\HCode{<body>}}{\HCode{
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="js/amige.js" type="text/javascript"/></body>}
    }
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: could you please post a complete example of tex and cfg files?

Comment: added example tex and cfg file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\Css` commands placed in the config file after `\begin{document}` are ignored. It is sometimes hard to figure out which configurations should be placed before and after `\begin{document}`. Best is to place it before at first and place it after in the case of problems.

I also little bit modified some other configurations, because non-valid html was produced:

```
\edef\hash{\string#}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\newcommand\leavepars{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}
  \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />\Hnewline}}
  \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
         href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />\Hnewline}}
  \Css { .cmcsc-10x-x-248{font-size:90\%;} } 
\Configure{TITLE+}{Digitarc PX3\texttrademark System}
\begin{document}
  \ConfigureEnv{titlepage}
    {\leavepars\HCode {<header class="navbar navbar-bright navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">}} 
    {\leavepars\HCode {</div></header>}} {} {}
  \ConfigureEnv{LOGOAMIGE}
    {\leavepars\HCode {
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="\#main-nav">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a href="\#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top">
    }}
    {\leavepars\HCode {
      </a>
      </div>
      <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    }}

\makeatletter
%\let\ifes@LaTeXe\iftrue
\makeatother
\Configure{BODY}{\HCode{<body>}}{\HCode{
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>\Hnewline
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>\Hnewline
    <script src="js/amige.js" type="text/javascript"></script>\Hnewline</body>}
    }
\EndPreamble
```

I've created `leavepars` command and placed it before `\HCode` commands which produced `<div>` elements. This will prevent tags crossing, such as `<div></p>`, which happened with the former definition. I've also added `\Configure{TITLE+}` configuration, because title element is empty otherwise, when you don't use `\title` command in your document. At last, I've commented out `%\let\ifes@LaTeXe\iftrue` which produced `LaTeXe` before `<title>`, so it obviously haven't worked anyway.

Comment: You are awesome, I've learned so much with your answers and questions here in stackexchange.

Comment: @Claudiordgz thank you. I am happy when my answers are helpful :)