# How can I override tex4ht's CSS in a single .css file?

Tags: tex4ht

I am trying to style tex4ht output using CSS in order to make a Kindle book. For example, I want to change the `verse` environment using `.verse { margin-left:2.5em; white-space:normal; }`

The Kindle guidelines ask for a single CSS file.  When I use `\CssFile` in my .cfg file, the CSS goes at the **start** of the .css file, and so it is overridden by the CSS generated by tex4ht. I can edit it manually to move my CSS to the end, but I would love to find a way to do this that has as few manual steps as possible.

[Changing a tex4ht css class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179345/changing-a-tex4ht-css-class) seems to ask the same question, but wound up with quite a different answer.

Sorry not to post an MWE, but willing to do so if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some information about `\CssFile` usage in [tex4ht documentation](http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn21.html#mn21-3)

You can include css files in the optional argument, multiple files must be delimited by commas. Place where css lines produced by `tex4ht` can be specified with line in `/* css.sty */` format. Note that you must place `\CssFile` AFTER `begin{document}` in the `.cfg` file.

Now some sample, we have two css files `sample.css`:

```
body{color:green}
```

and `hello.css`:

```
/* css.sty */
body{width:30em;margin: 0 auto;}
```

we can then put into `sample.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\CssFile[sample.css,hello.css]
\EndCssFile
\EndPreamble
```

because line `/* css.sty */` is in the second file, `css` generated by `tex4ht` is placed between contents of these two files:

```
/* sample.css from ahoj.tex (TeX4ht, 2014-09-20 17:00:00) */
  body{color:green}
/* start css.sty */
.cmtt-10{font-family: monospace;}
p.noindent { text-indent: 0em }
...
lot of lines
...
/* end css.sty */
body{width:30em;margin: 0 auto;}
```

and last warning: don't name any of these css files with same name as the `TeX` file, it would be overwritten then.

Comment: D'Oh!  I am embarrassed I had mindlessly copied an example which had the `/* css.sty */` at the end, skimming over its function in the documentation.  Based on your response, I realized that I just needed to move the `/* css.sty */` to the beginning of my CSS.  Sorry to take so much of your time!

Comment: @NatKuhn it's ok, I didn't know that you can use `/* css.sty */ inside included css files, so I learned something new too

Comment: Very kind of you!