# Invoke \CssFile via \AfterEndPreamble

Tags: tex4ht, html, latex2html, css

When running `htlatex <filename>` one can include CSS code via `\CssFile` and `\EndCssFile`.  This works fine as long as the code is included directly in the main document body.

I suspect this is the usual problem of including verbatim content in a macro, but is there a way to include CSS code but *not* have to put it in the actual document body.

### Notes:

- `pfdlatex` runs fine on both of these, problem is *only* with `htlatex` in the second MWE below.
- The CSS included is not really used in the HTML to be generated from this MWE.

---

### Code: Works, but document is cluttered

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}


\begin{document}
%% This works, but would rather it not be here so that the document is not cluttered.
\ifpdf
\else
      \CssFile 
         /* css.sty */ 
        .imageWrapperHi { height:99%; width:100%; text-align:center; page-break-inside:avoid; }
        .imageWrapperHi img { display:inline-block; height:100%; margin:0 auto; }  
      \EndCssFile
\fi
% -------
Some text.
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Desire a solution such as this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ifpdf
\else
    \AfterEndPreamble{%
          \CssFile 
             /* css.sty */ 
            .imageWrapperHi { height:99%; width:100%; text-align:center; page-break-inside:avoid; }
            .imageWrapperHi img { display:inline-block; height:100%; margin:0 auto; }  
          \EndCssFile
      }%
\fi
% -------

\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.cfg` file for this stuff, it is really not needed to clutter your documents with `tex4ht` configurations. It works with following file, `hello.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\CssFile 
/* css.sty */ 
.imageWrapperHi { height:99%; width:100%; text-align:center; page-break-inside:avoid; }
.imageWrapperHi img { display:inline-block; height:100%; margin:0 auto; }  
\EndCssFile
\EndPreamble
```

compile with

```
htlatex filename hello
```

for some information see this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202233/2891)