# make4ht - provide multiple configuration files

Tags: make4ht, css

In post [How can I override tex4ht's CSS in a single .css file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202229/how-can-i-override-tex4hts-css-in-a-single-css-file) the proposed solution requires to add a configuration file (namely *sample.cfg*). So, if I have *sample.tex* I may add *sample.cfg*.

However, in my case, I'm using an additional configuration file called *myMedia.cfg* to add some additional features to my document.

This means (if I got it right) that I should use `--config myMedia` to add this file to the compilation.

```
make4ht --utf8 --shell-escape sample.tex --config myMedia
```

Now, I end up with **two** configuration files:

- one with all the required commands for *myMedia*
- another one file with CSS configuration (the one with `\CssFile[] \EndCssFile`)

So:

- should I add something like `--config myMedia,sample` or `--config "myMedia,sample"`? well, it doesn't work... it loads only the first config file
- should I merge *myMedia.cfg* and *sample.cfg* together? It looks really ugly, but it actually works

Am I missing something?
Should I change the compiler?

Comment: I'm not really sure about this, but given the usual constructs in a `tex4ht` config file, such as `\Preamble{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\EndPreamble`, it will probably be difficult to have two of them (how would things be stacked/ordered then?). I haven't tested, but you might be able to use `\input{myMedia}` inside `sample.cfg` for a duly prepared `myMedia.tex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to add some additional information to the Darios answer.

Only one configuration file can be used by `tex4ht`, but its content
can be included by the `\input` command, so it is possible to reuse
parts of the configuration between different projects. It is possible to save the particular files in the local TEXMF directory, so they are accessible from any location on a computer.

In your case, as you created a custom package, you need to create a configuration file for that package, called `packagename.4ht`. You provided configuration file for your package `myMedia.4ht` in your answer. I would change it a bit:

```
\NewConfigure{myMedia}{2}%
\renewcommand\myMedia[1]{\a:myMedia#1\b:myMedia}
%\Configure{myMedia}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="video-content"><video width="640" height="480" playsinline autoplay muted loop><source src="}\NoFonts}{\HCode{" type="video/mp4"></video></div>}\EndNoFonts}

\Hinput{myMedia}
```

The `\NewConfigure{myMedia}{2}` command creates so called hooks which can be inserted into the redefined commands and configured using the `\Configure` command. It does exactly the same thing as the `\NewConfigure` from your answer, but it is a bit simpler.

It is better to keep the `\Configure` commands out of the package configuration files. Why? When `tex4ht` process the document preamble, it loads configuration files  for all used packages, in order to redefine commands and insert the hooks. After that,  configuration files for the current output format are executed. `tex4ht` can thus support  HTML, ODT and some more output formats. So configurations for HTML are provided in `html4.4ht` or `html5.4ht` files, for ODT format in `ooffice.4ht` etc. It is of course not possible for you to insert  your custom configurations to these files, as your edits would be removed in the next `tex4ht` update.

If you are sure to support only HTML, you can keep the `\Configure` command in `myMedia.4ht`, even if it is not the optimal solution. Another possibility is to put it in the `.cfg` file and last one is to create a custom output format. I will show this possibility just for the educational purposes:

Output formats are defined in the `tex4ht.4ht` file. This is the definition for `html5` format, for example:

```
\Configure{html5}{%
   \:CheckOption{info}\if:Option
               \Hinclude[*]{infoht4.4ht}\fi
   \:CheckOption{info}\if:Option
               \Hinclude[*]{infomml.4ht}\fi
   \Hinclude[*]{html4.4ht}%
   \Hinclude[*]{unicode.4ht}%
   \:CheckOption{mathml}\if:Option%
   \else\:CheckOption{mathml-}\fi%
   \if:Option%
      \Hinclude[*]{mathml.4ht}%
      \Hinclude[*]{html-mml.4ht}%
   \else
      \Hinclude[*]{html4-math.4ht}%
   \fi
   \:CheckOption{svg}%
             \if:Option \else\:CheckOption{svg-}\fi
             \if:Option \else\:CheckOption{svg-obj}\fi
             \if:Option \else\:CheckOption{svg-inline}\fi
             \if:Option \Hinclude[*]{svg-option.4ht}%
                        \:CheckOption{info}\if:Option \Hinclude[*]{infosvg.4ht}\fi
             \fi
   \Hinclude[*]{html5.4ht}%
}
```

The `\Configure` command here declares a code that is executed when the mark used as it's argument is used as an option for `tex4ht`. `html5` is added automatically by `make4ht` so this code is executed by default.

The custom output format can be defined in the `tex4ht.usr` file. It is possible to place it in the local TEXMF tree, for example `~/texmf/tex/latex/tex4ht/tex4ht.usr` seems to work. It's contents may look like this:

```
\Configure{myhtml5}{%
   \:CheckOption{info}\if:Option
               \Hinclude[*]{infoht4.4ht}\fi
   \:CheckOption{info}\if:Option
               \Hinclude[*]{infomml.4ht}\fi
   \Hinclude[*]{html4.4ht}%
   \Hinclude[*]{unicode.4ht}%
   \:CheckOption{mathml}\if:Option%
   \else\:CheckOption{mathml-}\fi%
   \if:Option%
      \Hinclude[*]{mathml.4ht}%
      \Hinclude[*]{html-mml.4ht}%
   \else
      \Hinclude[*]{html4-math.4ht}%
   \fi
   \:CheckOption{svg}%
             \if:Option \else\:CheckOption{svg-}\fi
             \if:Option \else\:CheckOption{svg-obj}\fi
             \if:Option \else\:CheckOption{svg-inline}\fi
             \if:Option \Hinclude[*]{svg-option.4ht}%
                        \:CheckOption{info}\if:Option \Hinclude[*]{infosvg.4ht}\fi
             \fi
   \Hinclude[*]{html5.4ht}%
   \Hinclude[*]{myconfig.4ht}
}
```

The difference to the previous listing is that the mark is named `myhtml5` and a new file is requested, `myconfig.4ht`. To request this output format, run

```
make4ht filename.tex "myhtml5"
```

The custom configurations can be then added to the `myconfig.4ht` file, which can be saved in the same location as `tex4ht.usr`:

```
\exit:ifnot{myMedia} 
\ConfigureHinput{myMedia}

\Configure{myMedia}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="video-content"><video width="640" height="480" playsinline autoplay muted loop><source src="}\NoFonts}
{\HCode{" type="video/mp4"></video></div>}\EndNoFonts}

\endinput\empty\empty\empty\empty\empty\empty 
\endinput
```

I've used the template for a package from [the tex4ht documentation](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn11.html#QQ1-11-66). In general, the code for a package needs to be enclosed in `\ConfigureHinput{packagename} ... \endinput`. This ensures that it is executed only when the package had been used in the document. You would get  warnings about missing configurations and probably unwanted HTML code in your document otherwise. The used packages are registered for the processing using the `\Hinput` command in the  package `.4ht` file.

The configuration for `myMedia` has been modified a bit, in order to handle correctly the paragraphs. The original configuration produced invalid HTML code due to this issue. You can copy  the `\Configure` command to the `.cfg` file or to the `myMedia.4ht` if you decide to use a simpler solutions. This is the only really necessary fix from my answer.

The last bit of information I want to provide in my answer is that it is possible to use a simpler command for inclusion of an external CSS file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{AddCss}{samplestyle.css}
\EndPreamble
```

It will not include the code from `samplestyle.css` to the main CSS file, it will just include a link to the HTML header. I think it is a preferable way in most cases.

This is the result of command

```
make4ht -um draft -c sample.cfg sample.tex "myhtml5"
```

```html
 <hr class="figure" /><div class="figure" 
>                                                                                                                           
<a id="x1-21"></a>                                                     
<div class="video-content"><video width="640" height="480" playsinline autoplay muted loop><source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<br /> <div class="caption" 
><span class="id">Figure 1: </span><span  
class="content">test</span></div><!--tex4ht:label?: x1-21 -->                                                   
   </div><hr class="endfigure" />
```

Comment: Hopefully, one day I'll get the hang of tex4ht & co.  ;-)  (+1 btw, interesting setup, I didn't know one could set a custom output type.)

Comment: One question: could `tex4ht.usr` and `myconfig.4ht` also be placed in the main document's working directory?

Comment: @gusbrs yes, I hope we sometimes get more collaborators. but it is hard without good documentation and my progress is pretty slow. especially since my last exhaustion :(

Comment: @gusbrs the files can be placed anywhere where they can be found by KPSE, the document directory has highest priority, so the files here should be used instead of ones in TEXMF tree

Comment: michal.h21 Thanks! And, well, I did try to weigh in on this one, but shyly. I'm not a pro, but I'm no noob either, and I am quickly out of my depth whenever I try something related to `tex4ht`. The documentation is indeed a critical issue, I think, but the sheer complexity of the system is also no mean challenge by itself. I've told you before, and tell you again: your (you and those involved) efforts are really appreciated. Anyway, please take care of yourself.

Comment: @gusbrs thanks for your kind words. I hope to be able to continue the work soon

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just followed what @gusbrs suggested in the comment below (thanks a lot!) and he was right: there is **no need** of any *myMedia.cfg*. What was in there, it could just be moved into *myMedia.4ht*.

This solution allows to completely separate the global configuration file (*sample.cfg*) from other-packages files (such as *myMedia.4ht*).

The current ***working*** setup is the following:

- *sample.tex* contains the `\usepackage{myMedia}` command in the document preamble;

  ```latex
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % may use latin1 instead of utf8
  \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
  \usepackage{myMedia}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
     \centering
     \myMedia{test.mp4}
     \caption{test}
  \end{figure}

  \end{document}
  ```
- *sample.cfg* that acts like an actual configuration file;

  ```latex
  \Preamble{xhtml}
  \begin{document}
  \CssFile[samplestyle.css]
  \EndCssFile
  \EndPreamble
  ```
- *myMedia.4ht*

  ```latex
  \NewConfigure{myMedia}[2]%
  {
      \def\a:myMedia{#1}%
      \def\b:myMedia{#2}%
  }
  \renewcommand\myMedia[1]{\a:myMedia#1\b:myMedia}
  \Configure{myMedia}{\HCode{<div class="video-content"><video width="640" height="480" playsinline autoplay muted loop><source src=}\NoFonts}{\HCode{ type="video/mp4"></video></div>}\EndNoFonts}
  ```
- *myMedia.sty*

  ```latex
  \ProvidesPackage{myMedia}
  \newcommand\myMedia[1]{#1}
  \endinput
  ```
- *samplestyle.css* contains the CSS styling for the document;

  ```latex
  /* css.sty */
  body {
      text-align: justify;
  }
  ```

The command line is

```
make4ht --utf8 --shell-escape sample.tex --config sample
```

For those who may need a MWE, here it is: [mysample](http://www.mediafire.com/file/9x7wqzx7fv5rbax/mysample.zip/file)

Comment: Glad to see it works. But, if I understand correctly now, `myMedia` is a package you load. If this is the case, you could simply use a file `myMedia.4ht` in the same folder with that content. No further intervention required.

Comment: Well, I already have such file, but not as configure file! No better explain the overall setup, I added the full list of files that I have in my folder. I don't know if there is actually another way to restructure the code to get rid of some of them.

Comment: Dario, as far as I understand, I usually take the `.4ht` as a container of configuration instructions associated with certain packages. The `.cfg` is somewhere where you can globally set (or override) things. Did you try to include what you are trying to put in `myMedia.cfg` alongside the rest of `myMedia.4ht`? Anyway, it is somewhat hard to help, as you do not provide a MWE...

Comment: Oh, sure. I have a MWE if someone is interested:
[sample example](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/h9dieo0rcpfi1/sample)

Comment: Oh, yes @gusbrs! You are right! I can get rid of _myMedia.cfg_. I didn't know it was possible. I blindly followed the suggestion of different posts; I never tried to compact all the statements just in _myMedia.4ht_. I will update the answer and add a MWE for future reference. Thanks again for your suggestions

Comment: Nice. But please include the MWE as a code in your answer (or, if in new questions, in the question itself). Links to external sites leave some weary and it renders the question later useless to others, if the links cease to function.